# How .NET Core can authenticate from founded other app cookie?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

An website created by Node.js/Express.js. Authentication provided by Passport.js. After login Express.js creates cookie.
Subdomain will be created with .Net Core. And it if found cookie, has to automatically authenticate user.

I know .Net Core Identity.
But I can't get any information in Google about this solution.
How .Net Core app can authenticate if cookie is founded?

Comment: The framework gets cookie value, decrypts and deserializes it and then fetches auth data from it. That's how cookie authentication works

Comment: @Alexander Express.js cookie has only sessionId. .Net Core has to check it with Mondodb collection sessions.  I don't  understand - how cookie get? Its name nature_app. I can with Identity? Without it?

Comment: It's hard to say wihout your `Startup.cs` code, particulary auth configuartion